# Connection with two SQL client to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection

I have two sql client on two systems having different tables , and One SQL server having all the tables.
This is designed to sync to Sync data of both the local clients to a single SQL server. 
I am able to connect one sql client with sql server but I am not able to connect with second sql client.
Even I am not able to see the second client on server. 
I tried disabling firewall, Antivirus. All connection are on LAN . 
I doubt the port of sql server is reading from single port that's why I am not able to connect with second client, but I am not sure about this . I don't know where I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  found the solution, I had used two databases because of that my port was occupied, I uninstalled the second Mysql and now it is working fine. I had disabled antivirus also.